# How do I use R to download multiple CSV files from a url at once, and also only download a certain number of lines (ex. lines 3-13 only)?

Tags: r, csv, file, download

```
type here

library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/market-reports/#nt=%2FMarketReportType%3AHistorical%20MCP%2FMarketReportName%3AASM%20Real-Time%20Final%20Market%20MCPs%20(csv)&t=10&p=0&s=MarketReportPublished&sd=desc"

# Scrape the webpage to extract the URLs
page <- read_html(url)
file_links <- page %>% html_nodes("a[href$='.csv']") %>% html_attr("href")

# Create a directory to store the downloaded files
dir.create("downloaded_files")

# Define the range of rows to extract from each file
start_row <- 3
end_row <- 13

# Loop over each file URL and download the file
for (file_link in file_links) {
  filename <- basename(file_link)
  file_path <- paste0("downloaded_files/", filename)
  
  # Download the file
  download.file(file_link, destfile = file_path)
  
  # Read the downloaded file
  data <- read.csv(file_path, skip = start_row - 1, nrows = end_row - start_row + 1)
  
  # Do something with the data, e.g., print the extracted rows
  print(data)
}
```

it creates an empty folder on my desktop, but there seems to be nothing in it. I'm not sure if its a code problem, or if there's something on the url side of things that I have to figure out

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from the code where you try to extract the links. I think it is because {rvest} doesn't read Javascript and the site apparently needs it to show the documents.

Nevertheless, I think there are other options. The links of the csv's have a similar structure. So, I would do the following.

```
date_start <- as.Date("2023-06-06")
date_end <- as.Date("2022-06-06")

list_dates <- format(seq(date_end, date_start,
                  by = "day"),
                  "%Y%m%d")

for (date in list_dates) {
  
  file_link <- paste0("https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/",
                      date,
                      "_asm_rtmcp_final.csv")
  filename <- basename(file_link)
  file_path <- paste0("downloaded_files/", filename)
  
  # Download the file
  download.file(file_link, destfile = file_path)
  
  # Read the downloaded file
  data <-  read.csv(file_link, skip = 3, header = T)

  # Do something with the data, e.g., print the extracted rows
  print(data)
}
```